# Можно ли как-то управлять чатом в Minecraft с помощью python

Tags: python, python-3.x, minecraft

Хочу написать таймер с уведомлениями о респавне босса. Нужно чтоб спустя N кол-во времени игроку в майнкрафте выводилось уведомление, сообщение о спавне. Не имею доступа к файлам сервера. Т.е я обычный игрок, играющий на их сервере.

Comment: В этом случае разве что имитировать ввод с клавиатуры. Посмотрите библиотеку `pyautogui` или `keyboard`. Если надо, могу привести пример

Comment: denisnumb, это будет не в свёрнутом режиме, и будет сильно мешать при пвп =(

Comment: Можете попробовать включать какое-то голосовое сообщение по истечению таймера.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать MCPI у него очень узкий функционал но тем не менее это схоже с тем что вы хотите. Так же можно попробовать бинды. Но Python слабо подходит для этих задач.

```
import keyboard

     def build():
       print("Прописываем взаимодействие с командами")

     keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+f', build)
     keyboard.wait('esc')
```

Comment: Для работы MCPI нужно устанавливать плагин на сервер, что не подходит для меня =( Насчёт биндов. Они будут открывать чат, что остановит к примеру ПВП и меня убьют =(

Comment: Иначе никак, можно попробовать сделать свой голосовой ввод или например у Алисы есть уже готовый помощник майнкрафт но это только для C++ версии.

Comment: DaYa, спасибо за ответ. Думаю буду писать на C++. Закрою вопрос! Всего хорошего!

Answer (score 0):

```
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft
import time
#Импортируем библиотеку для игры

mc = Minecraft.create()

def Propiska():
    time.sleep() #В скобках количество секунд.
    mc.postToChat('Твой текст')
```

Не работал с библиотекой, но думаю - так.

Подобный вопрос: [Как писать в чат майнкрафт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1230327/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-minecraft-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-python)